# jquery ajax parse xml, split array

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, arrays, split

is it possible to get the last value of an string, that looks like this for example:

```
tm="1610612741|Bulls|Chicago|CHI"
```

and save it as a variable?

Something like that:

var tm = $(this).find('htm').attr('tm');

**I only need the "CHI" string.**
I tried everything, but what i found doesnt work. I get the string and the var from an xml file.
Also is it possible to parse the xml from a "live" version, like http://www.exampledomain.com/test.xml?

Appreciate your help!

Nicole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tm = '1610612741|Bulls|Chicago|CHI';
var arr = tm.split('|');
var lastPart = arr[arr.length - 1];

alert(lastPart); // CHI
```

Comment: wow thank you, it works perfectly. almost what i got, but i guess i got confused, still learning :) thank you!

Comment: Great! Please mark my solution as the answer if that is the case.